# How do I reference certain digits of an integer and compare them? Java

Tags: java

I've been working on a program that determines a `4 digit number` based on certain `parameters`.

One of the `parameters` that I've been trying to implement is that the digits of this `int` cannot repeat, and that's where I'm starting to have trouble.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class FourDigit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int poss = 0;

        //counts from 1000 to 3999
        for (int counter = 1000; counter < 4000; counter++)
        {
            // Makes sure the number is divisible by 10 and 5
            if (counter % 5 == 0 && counter % 10 == 0)
            {
                // Prints and counts all of the possibilities
                System.out.print(counter + " ");
                poss++;
            }

            // What I've been trying...
            String string = Integer.toString(counter);

            if (string.substring(1,2) == string.substring(2,3))
                System.out.println("Hello");

        }
        System.out.println(poss);
    }

}
```

p.s. the `println` is temporary, just to check if it works.

The numbers must be in between 1000 and 4000, cannot start with 0, and must end in 0. Also, the 2nd digit must be even, and there is no repetition allowed.

Thanks, Dccciz :)

Comment: the specification is rather unclear. 2nd digit and 4th digit must be 0, but no repetitions allowed? and it would be rather usefull, if you listed all rules for deriving the 4digit number from the input.

Comment: You **never** compare the content of two strings with `==`. `==` compares  the references, not the contents. Always use `String.equals()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the number is 4 digit, just make it this way.

```
int d1,d2,d3,d4;

d1 = num % 10;
num /= 10;
d2 = num % 10;
num /= 10;
d3 = num % 10;
num /= 10;
d4 = num % 10;
```

And you also can make it inside of an array which written in a function which you call it during your for loop:

```
private int[] splitDigits(int num){

    int n = num;       //making a copy for not rowen the num we got
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 4){
        arr[i++] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now you can call this function within your for loop:

```
for (int counter = 1000; counter < 4000; counter++) {
    int[] digits = splitDigits(counter);
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest solved using a String approach, requiring only one line:

```
boolean hasRepeats = Integer.toString(number).matches(".*(.).*\\1.*");
```